# I'd like to change Day view via fullCalender.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm setting as below via fullCalender.js

```
views:{
        month:{ titleFormat:'YYYY' +"年" +'MM'+"月"},
        //,week: { titleFormat:"MMM d[ yyyy]{ '&#8212;'[ MMM] d yyyy}"},
        //,week:{ titleFormat:"DD MMMM YYYY"},
        day:{ titleFormat:'MM/DD'}
    },
```

I'd like to change day of date view.
For example, Jul 2nd is cell is writing "2" via fullCalender function.
I like to cahnge "2" to "07/02".
I prefer [enter link description here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeFormat) But, I'm not able to understand.
I need your kind help.
now My program view  as below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MGXr.jpg)
Thank you!

Comment: I use JQuery 1.12.4
JQuery UI 1.12.0
fullCalender 3.9.0
moment 2.22.2

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the output you're seeing?

Comment: Yep, I upload now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with fullcalendar, I've found that it gives you a lot of hooks to get at data but you sometimes have to get a bit creative when you want to perform updates. Here's what I found was doable using the demo included with FullCalendar called `fullcalendar-3.9.0/demos/basic-views.html`.

I used the [dayRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayRender) hook that gives me access to each cell as it's rendered. This gives you two arguments, `date`, and `cell` (which is the cell instance).

You can get the cell's `data-date` property with:

```
const dataDate = cell.data('date');
```

Then you can match that with the spot where the date is actually rendered with the following:

```
$(`td[data-date="${dataDate}"] a`).text(date.format('MM/DD'));
```

All together, this will look like:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
  const dataDate = cell.data('date');
  $(`td[data-date="${dataDate}"] a`).text(date.format('MM/DD'));
},
```

[image]